# Chain of sequences, such that $a_{k+1}(n)$ completes $a_k(n)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, additive-combinatorics

We say that the sequence $a_{k+1}(n)$ is a complete sequence of $a_k(n)$ if:
(1) Every term of $a_k(n)$ can be written as a sum of *distinct* terms of $a_{k+1}(n)$.
(2) $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_k(n)}{a_{k+1}(n)}=0$.
(Possibly there are more than one choices for $a_{k+1}(n)$ if $a_k(n)$ is given).

We can see that letting $a_1(n)=n$, then $a_{2}(n)=F_n$ (the Fibonacci numbers) is an easy (but possibly not unique) choice since by [Zeckendorf's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem) every positive integer can be represented as the sum of one or more distinct Fibonacci numbers.
We can see also that an easy choice is $a_3(n)=2^n$ since every natural number is a sum of distinct powers of $2$ (and so are the Fibonacci numbers) and obviously,  $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{F_n}{2^n}=0$.

Question 1: Can we find $a_4(n)$ given the previous $a_3(n)$.?
Question 2: Is there a general method to compute $a_{k+1}(n)$ if $a_k(n)$ is given?

Comment: By "find $a_4$" do you mean find any quadruple $a_1, \cdots,a_4$ or find an $a_4$ for your given $a_3$?

Comment: Find $a_4$ given my $a_3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, such $a_4$ does not exist.

Surely, we may assume $a_4$ to be increasing. Now consider a representation of some $a_3(n)$. If it contains only elements of $a_4$ which appear in the representations of $a_3(k)$ with $k<n$, then $a_3(n)\leq a_3(1)+\dots+a_3(n-1)$ which is wrong.

Therefore, the representations of $a_3(k)$ with $k\leq n$ contain at least $n$ distinct terms of $a_4$, so $a_4(n)\leq a_3(n)$. This contradicts the limit condition